# CentOS Apache server question

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, configuration

On my CentOS virtual machine I set up an Apache server.
I followed this link: [How to set up Apache server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7).

Then everything worked fine as expected; however,
when I removed the `example.com` entry from the `/etc/hosts` file, I expected it to reach for `/var/www/html` instead of `example.com` still however it still reached only for `example.com` index html when I reach for my local IP address.
I just want to understand when should it prefer to reach out for folders like `example.com` and leave out `/var/www/html/`.

It confused me a bit. I want to know when is this one used and when is the other used as in `/var/www/example.com` and `/var/www/html` respectively.

Comment: Did you do "service httpd reload"?

Comment: i did restart the computer after every edit ,  i did try that order now after trying still shows example.com, when i remove example.com from sites-enabled example2.com takes place , when i remove both example.com and example2.com the index.html in /var/www/html is finally the one loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i got what happened in case anyone faces the same issue,
In the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`  i included the virtual hosts file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d` which specified the listen id for

> `<VirtualHost *:80>`

Which means by this documentation [VirtualHosts Common Questions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) that it will listen on all the ips, not letting the main server in `/var/www/html` serve any requests.

And because "example.com" is declared before "example2.com" (assuming that '.' comes before '2' in folder organization) it has the highest priority to serve the requests.

For example if we were to change "example2.com" to "aexample2.com" it will have a higher priority because it will be declared first due to begin read first from the folder `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled` because 'a' comes before 'e' in alphabetical order (As my tests showed).